# Reporting Services - Editing multiple (similar) reports at once?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, service, reporting-services, reporting

I'm editing 20+ similar "reporting services"-reports in Visual Studio 2010, and a common annoyance is that whenever I have to make a slight change to the reports (For example change the font, add a parameter or add a textbox), I have to go through them all to make the change. I know there is a way to make templates, but my problem is to make a change to multiple after they are created (as far as I know the template feature is only for the creation of the report documents).

Any help is greatly appreciated, and please let me know if you need further information.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it helps but you can try to use [Subreports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239314.aspx)

Comment: I would think that it's too late for me to restructure my reports using subreports, but that might be something to consider for future projects. Did you mean I could use a "shell" with report header etc. and present the individual reports as subreports in this shell-report, or did you have something else in mind? I would guess I'd still have to handle the subreports individually though (I haven't used subreports, thus all I know about them is the linked page)? Thanks for the answer nonetheless!

Comment: I thought I was right but now after a little analysis it seems that subreports would not resolve your problem... I see that it would allow you to reuse the internal reports not the "shell".

However you can also consider the report parts: (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633670). I think they will help you to save the headers, logos and other stuff to the separate "components" and use them in each your report. Frankly speaking I never tried it.

Comment: Thanks again. Report parts would probably be something to consider for future projects, as you probably use that kind of structure from the beginning of the project crafting. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I have a feeling that Microsoft has prioritized ease of use above efficiency, hence the large amount of dropdown menus.